# magento2 share inventory between products

Tags: magento2

I'm looking for a solution to share inventory between several products. I don't know if Magento 2 can handle this natively, or if I need an extension to handle this.

Let's say I have four products. These products should subtract from the same inventory, but at different quantities.

- Product 1 should subtract 1 from stock qty
- Product 2 should subtract 12 from stock qty
- Product 3 should subtract 144 from stock qty

The products are the same, but some are in bigger packages. If my stock status is 144, and I buy Product 1, Product 3 should be out of stock. Hope this makes sense, and that someone can help :)